# Correlated query in oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle

I need help with a correlated subquery in Oracle Sql.
The problem is, that the second level deep subquery contains the daily.day, so this query results in an error.

```
DAILY - columns: daily_id, day, emp_details_id, worked_hour 

EMP_DETAILS - columns: emp_details_id, valid_from, valid_to, detail_type, detail_value
```

I'd like to get the detail_value for each row, where the row's day is between ed.valid_from and ed.valid_to. Then I'd like to take the row for this day, where ed.valid_from is the greatest (most recent). 
So I'd like the most recent valid detail value for the given emp_details_id

Example: (I only wrote the needed columns)

DAILY

```
day = '2016-03-02', emp_details_id = 1
day = '2016-03-04', emp_details_id = 1
```

EMP_DETAILS

```
valid_from = '2016-01-01', valid_to = '2016-12-31', detail_value = 6, emp_details_id = 1
valid_from = '2016-03-02', valid_to = '2016-12-31', detail_value = 7, emp_details_id = 1
valid_from = '2016-03-03', valid_to = '2016-12-31', detail_value = 8, emp_details_id = 1
valid_from = '2016-03-01', valid_to = '2016-12-31', detail_value = 10, emp_details_id = 2
```

Result:

```
day = '2016-03-02', valid_from = '2016-03-02', valid_to = '2016-12-31', detail_value = 7, emp_details_id = 1
day = '2016-03-04', valid_from = '2016-03-03', valid_to = '2016-12-31', detail_value = 8, emp_details_id = 1
```

My query:

```
SELECT
   da.*,
   ed.detail_value
FROM
   DAILY da
   INNER JOIN EMP_DETAILS ed 
      ON(da.emp_details_id = ed.emp_details_id)
WHERE
   ed.detail_value =
   (SELECT worktime.detail_value
      FROM
      (SELECT 
          ed2.detail_value
       FROM
          EMP_DETAILS ed2
       WHERE
          ed2.valid_from <= da.day AND --error
          ed2.valid_to >= da.day AND --error
          ed2.emp_details_id = ed.emp_details_id --error
       ORDER BY ed2.valid_from DESC
      ) worktime

    WHERE 
       ROWNUM = 1
   )
```

Comment: `SELECT worktime.detail_value...` - where is `worktime` defined? Likewise, `SELECT d.*...` - where is `d` defined?

Comment: It helps to include the actual errors you get. Invalid identifier or similar, presumably?

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out. Edited my question.

Comment: have you tried changing the alias name for the DAILY table? (since most likely your system is case insensitive - so just to eliminate that possibility of an error, try to give another alias instead of daily)

Comment: Why are you expecting different detail_values; for both `daily.day` values, the latest `ed.date_from` is 2016-03-02, so they should both get detail ID 7?

Comment: Yeah, true, corrected it.

Comment: you can use aliases of query only in direct subquery (if subquery is in where clause)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can avoid the self-joins by using an analytic query to rank the joined rows by the latest `ed.valid_from` date for the `daily` record. The basic query is something like:

```
SELECT
   daily.*,
   ed.*,
   rank() over (partition by daily.emp_details_id, daily.day
     order by ed.valid_from DESC) rnk
FROM
   DAILY daily
INNER JOIN EMP_DETAILS ed 
ON daily.emp_details_id = ed.emp_details_id
AND ed.valid_from <= daily.day
AND ed.valid_to >= daily.day;

DAY        EMP_DETAILS_ID VALID_FROM VALID_TO   DETAIL_VALUE EMP_DETAILS_ID        RNK
---------- -------------- ---------- ---------- ------------ -------------- ----------
2016-03-02              1 2016-03-02 2016-12-31            7              1          1
2016-03-02              1 2016-01-01 2016-12-31            6              1          2
2016-03-04              1 2016-03-03 2016-12-31            8              1          1
2016-03-04              1 2016-03-02 2016-12-31            7              1          2
2016-03-04              1 2016-01-01 2016-12-31            6              1          3
```

The record with the greatest date is ranked 1, so you can put that in a subquery and filter on the generated `rnk` column:

```
SELECT
   emp_details_id, day, detail_value
FROM
   (
   SELECT
      daily.day,
      daily.emp_details_id,
      ed.detail_value,
      rank() over (partition by daily.emp_details_id, daily.day
        order by ed.valid_from DESC) rnk
   FROM
      DAILY daily
   INNER JOIN EMP_DETAILS ed 
   ON daily.emp_details_id = ed.emp_details_id
   AND ed.valid_from <= daily.day
   AND ed.valid_to >= daily.day
)
WHERE
   rnk = 1;

EMP_DETAILS_ID DAY        DETAIL_VALUE
-------------- ---------- ------------
             1 2016-03-02            7
             1 2016-03-04            8
```

From the data is doesn't look likely that you'd have two matching records, but if you did (if 7 and 8 we both valid from the same date) then this would return two rows. You would need to adjust the partition by clause to choose how to break the tie. (You can also use dense_rank, row_number etc. but the same applies - if there can be a tie you should specify how to break it).

Answer (score 1):

You need to query DAILY in the subquery. Also, you can get rid of the nested subquery, ORDER BY ... DESC, and ROWNUM = 1 by using the MAX function in the subquery, with the [FIRST or LAST](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions065.htm) aggregate variation to get the DETAIL_VALUE corresponding to the latest date:

```
SELECT d.*,
       ed.DETAIL_VALUE
FROM DAILY d
INNER JOIN EMP_DETAILS ed 
  ON ed.EMP_DETAILS_ID = d.EMP_DETAILS_ID
WHERE (d.EMP_DETAILS_ID, d.DAY, ed.DETAIL_VALUE) IN
          (SELECT d2.EMP_DETAILS_ID, d2.DAY,
                MAX(ed2.DETAIL_VALUE) KEEP (DENSE_RANK LAST ORDER BY ed2.VALID_FROM)
             FROM DAILY d2
             INNER JOIN EMP_DETAILS ed2
               ON ed2.EMP_DETAILS_ID = d2.EMP_DETAILS_ID
             WHERE d2.DAY BETWEEN ed2.VALID_FROM
                              AND ed2.VALID_TO
             GROUP BY d2.EMP_DETAILS_ID, d2.DAY);

DAY        EMP_DETAILS_ID DETAIL_VALUE
---------- -------------- ------------
2016-03-02              1            7
2016-03-04              1            8
```

In this simplified example the subquery on its own actually finds all the information you need:

```
SELECT d2.EMP_DETAILS_ID, d2.DAY,
     MAX(ed2.DETAIL_VALUE) KEEP (DENSE_RANK LAST ORDER BY ed2.VALID_FROM)
    FROM DAILY d2
  INNER JOIN EMP_DETAILS ed2
    ON ed2.EMP_DETAILS_ID = d2.EMP_DETAILS_ID
  WHERE d2.DAY BETWEEN ed2.VALID_FROM
                   AND ed2.VALID_TO
  GROUP BY d2.EMP_DETAILS_ID, d2.DAY;

EMP_DETAILS_ID DAY        MAX(ED2.DETAIL_VALUE)KEEP(DENSE_RANKLAS
-------------- ---------- ---------------------------------------
             1 2016-03-02                                       7
             1 2016-03-04                                       8
```

and you could get the other fields from DAILY quite simply; for other EMP_DETAILS you'd need to use more MAX KEEP DENSE_RANK formulations. If that gets too messy or complicated then using that as a subquery and joining to it, as in the first example, might be clearer - but would be less efficient as it has to hit both the tables twice.

Best of luck.

Comment: I don't think `MAX(ed2.DETAIL_VALUE)` is right; it should be the detail value that matches the max valid_from date. I think... Which you could do with keep dense rank or similar, but you'd need to include the d.day in the grouping and select list. (I can edit in what I mean if you like; you can always roll back if you don't agree?)

Comment: @AlexPoole - sure, go ahead. Now that I look at it again I think you're right, and my `DENSE RANK`-fu is fairly weak. I'll flip it over to community wiki.

Answer (score 0):

your query with minimal change:

```
SELECT
  da.*,
  ed.detail_value
FROM
  DAILY da 
inner join EMP_DETAILS ed ON da.emp_details_id = ed.emp_details_id  
where ed.detail_value =
  (SELECT detail_value
    FROM ( 
      SELECT *
      FROM EMP_DETAILS 
      ORDER BY valid_from DESC) ed2
    WHERE ROWNUM =1 and
    ed2.valid_from <= da.day AND --error
    ed2.valid_to >= da.day AND --error
    ed2.emp_details_id = ed.emp_details_id --error
  )
```